# Best strategy to reduce DB connections in a multithreading application using the Qt framework

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, qt

I have a server that communicates to a lot of devices (>1000). Each connection has its own thread. Now, I realized that I would have to set my mysql config to allow >1000 open concurrent connections what seems to be a very bad idea in my opinion.

Qt docs say that every thread needs its own connection: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module

So, I have to call

```
 QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "thread specific string");
```

in every thread.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Honestly speaking I don't know much about QT but if I take your problem in general then I would advise you to create a "Connection Pool"
2. If you don't want or can't implement a Connection Pool then its fine to increase Max_Connections in MySQL configuration and leave the pooling on MySQL, it has its own Connection Pooling mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for your time. 1.: using the qt connection pool mechanism will only allow to have multiple connections inside one thread. So, this would not help here. 2.: max_connections of > 1000? is this really an option or would the create/kill of the connections bring the server to its knees? What are you reffering to with "has its own Connection Pooling"? Please specify a bit more, do you mean an extra service like SQL Relay or is the functionality you are referring already part of mysql core itself?

Comment: Upto my knowledge MySQL has embedded connection pool i.e. you don't need another instance of MySQL rather it will handle pooling for you. But remember that connection pooling works on idle connections i.e. if some thread has created some connection and its not in use then some other thread may use it. But in worst case if all threads are continuously using their allocated connections then you can use maximum MAX_CONNECTIONS connections.

Comment: This sounds promising. Now, I just have to know what I have to do in qt to let the mysql service know that the connection is idle: Do you think `QSqlDatabase::close()` should do the job? I wonder if it will be a problem if I open/close the DB connection on each data packet I receive in the connection thread. Thank you for any opinion.

Comment: Thank you both @r_ahlskog and Mian Zeshan Farooqi for your very valuable comments. I mark this one as the solution, but the DB-Manager-Thread I did not try because of more implementation time. What I did: I left the connection handling to the mysql service (some sort of), because I close the connections now at several points in my code and re-open it before I need it. So, i still have a connection object for every thread but I take the trade off of opening and closing them often. CPU does not seem to care much. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would think some sort of resource pooling would be appropriate here.

Depending on the database workload from the >1000 device threads a single database thread could maybe manage it or then you will need several database threads.

Then setup a queuing system from the device threads to the database thread(s), where the devices push the work and the database thread(s) pulls work units off and perform the query.

I just realised that I was thinking of writing to database only like some sort of logging, and  this idea may not work without modification if what you are doing is reading from the database and writing to devices.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Pooling would be my favorite solution the other is closing and opening the DB connection on each incoming data packet (what does not make me feel real good). Your idea is good with the DB-Manager thread. My problem there is the communication between the connection and the DB thread. I can only think of the qt signaling concept to send data from the connection threads to the DB-Manager thread. But this is event based unidirectional (or almost: setting up connections from the DB-Manager back to the dynamically created connection threads makes me feel bad too.)